# Writing Program in Python with different levels(or cases)

Tags: python

I want to write a program in python having 7-8 different cases.
like- Case 1, Name, Case 2- DOB, Case 3- City... etc

Also, I want to take the input from user and store in mysql.

How can I have that in Python? Any ideas?

I have my code-

Kindly ignore indentations-

```
levels = 1
    i= 1
   
    while (i<=5):
               
        if (levels==i and (re.search(r'\bhello\b', incoming_msg)) or re.search(r'\bhi\b', incoming_msg)):
        # incoming_msg=='hello' or incoming_msg=='hi' :
            reply = ("Kindly provide your full name")
           
            print(levels)
            msg.body(reply)
            return str(resp)
           
            levels=levels +1
            i+=1
       
           
        if (levels==i and incoming_msg.isdigit()==False):
            print(levels)
            reply = ("Thank you for providing your name.\n\n"
                "Kindly provide your DOB:\n")
           
           
            msg.body(reply)
            return str(resp)
           
            levels = 3
 
        if((levels==i) and and incoming_msg.isdigit()==False):
       
            reply =('Kindly provide your DOB.")
             
            msg.body(reply)
            return str(resp)
            i =4
            levels = 4
   
   
        if((levels==i) and incoming_msg.isdigit()==True)):
     
            reply =("Thanks for the info")
             
            msg.body(reply)
            return str(resp)
            i = 5
            levels = 5
             
                else:
        # prompt user to check his/her query
            reply = "Sorry, but I didn't understand your query.  Kindly select the correct option"

        msg.body(reply)
        return str(resp)
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: You need more specifications in your question. Please specify what are you trying to say about case .., post codes if any. For the part of writing the input to mysql, you can use the MySQLdb module for python 3. You can learn more about it on www.mysqlturorial.org.

Comment: I want to take user input. it's kind of form asking for basic details.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you do cases.

```
case = input("what is your case? ")

if case == "nominative":
    print("mensa")

elif case == "vocative":
    print("mensa")

elif case == "accusative":
    print("mensam")

elif case == "genitive":
    print("mensae")

elif case == "dative":
    print("mensae")

elif case == "ablative":
    print("mensa")

else:
    print("never heard of it")
```

Comment: But I have different cases, I mean questions to ask. How can I implement the same?

Comment: Just ask whatever question you want and then have a bunch of `if` and `elif` lines in the same way.

Comment: Okzz. Thanks. Will give it a short.

Comment: Sorry buddy. Not implementing!